# How to reconnect socket.io without a page refresh once connection is disconnected from client?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, socket.io

I have logs data coming from the server using socket.io, I have a requirement where the user should be able to disconnect and reconnect socket.io by having stop/play buttons on the UI side, so problem here is when I disconnect the socket its working but when I am trying to reconnect its not creating the connection again. How can I reconnect socket.io without a page refresh?

Factory.js

```
angular.module('loggingApp').factory('socket', function ($rootScope) {
    'use strict';
        var server = 'http://localhost:3000';
        var socket = io.connect(server,{'forceNew': true });
        return {
            on: function (eventName, callback) {
                socket.on(eventName, function () {
                    var args = arguments;
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        callback.apply(socket, args);
                    });
                });
            },
            emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
                socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {
                    var args = arguments;
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        if (callback) {
                            callback.apply(socket, args);
                        }
                    });
                })
            },
            disconnect: function () {
                socket.disconnect();
            },
            reconnect: function () {
                console.log('socket.reconnect()');
                //socket.io.reconnect();
               socket = io.connect(server,{'forceNew': true });
            },
        };

});
```

ctrl.js

```
 $scope.playLogs = function(){
        console.log('inside start function');
        socket.reconnect();
    }
    $scope.stopLogs = function(){
        console.log('inside stop funtion');
        socket.disconnect();
    }
```

Comment: why just disconnect ? disconnect() is a function that is "triggered" when you loose connection, close your browser, etc ...
 
If not receiving sockets messages is what you want, you can set a boolean variable "active" who is checked before sending message

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to stop reacting to socket events instead?

Comment: yes i am disconnecting because i dont want logs coming consistently

Comment: fairly new to angular and socket.io, i did not get boolean variable idea how we will invoke from controller so you want me to have variable in factory the will check `on` method if flag is active or not ?

Comment: @E.K, would the socket.io code be smart enough to reconnect if the connection is lost over time (i.e. if you do not use a connection, often they get dropped after some time, like FTP often kicks you out after 5 min. of inaction.)

Comment: To reconnect, you just execute your original connection code all over again.  Put into a function so you can call it upon demand.

Comment: Thanks putting into new function socket.connect() reconnected to server.

Comment: @hussain kindly can you help me plzz for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52791960/auto-reconnect-socket-io-in-angular-to-node